# StackOverflowError in JSF composite component recursion

Tags: jsf, recursion, primefaces, jsf-2.2, composite-component

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8446728/1797006 using the JSF composite component `nested:cif` recursively and terminating the recursion with `c:if` should work:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:nested="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/nested"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="theAttr"
                type="richtercloud.jsf.avoid.nested.rendered.evaluation.Entity0"
                required="true"/>
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <h:outputLabel value="Hello World!"/>
        <c:if test="#{cc.attrs.theAttr.reference ne null}">
            <nested:cif theAttr="#{cc.attrs.theAttr.reference}"/>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="#{cc.attrs.theAttr.reference eq null}">
            <h:outputLabel value="recursion terminated"/>
        </c:if>
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

when called as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:nested="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/nested">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <nested:cif theAttr="#{backingBean0.reference}"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Backing bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class BackingBean0 implements Serializable {
    private Entity0 reference = new Entity0(new Entity0(null));

    public Entity0 getReference() {
        return reference;
    }

    public void setReference(Entity0 reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting a

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:557)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.get(ComponentStateHelper.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.get(UIComponentBase.java:2386)
    at com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap.get(CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver.java:393)
    at javax.el.MapELResolver.getValue(MapELResolver.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeValueExpression.getValue(ContextualCompositeValueExpression.java:158)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.get(UIComponentBase.java:2427)
    at com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap.get(CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver.java:393)
    at javax.el.MapELResolver.getValue(MapELResolver.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeValueExpression.getValue(ContextualCompositeValueExpression.java:158)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.get(UIComponentBase.java:2427)
    at com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap.get(CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver.java:393)
    at javax.el.MapELResolver.getValue(MapELResolver.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeValueExpression.getValue(ContextualCompositeValueExpression.java:158)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.get(UIComponentBase.java:2427)
    at com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap.get(CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver.java:393)
    at javax.el.MapELResolver.getValue(MapELResolver.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
[a few more hundred lines]
```

When I place a debugger breakpoint in `Entity0.getReference` I see that it's invoked once before the `StackOverflowError`.

Afaik the only other issue covered in other SO question is [using `rendered` to break the recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923220/how-to-stop-recursive-composite-component-from-including-itself-recursively) which doesn't work because of view build time vs. view render time.

I expect the recursion to cause the "Hello world!" label to be displayed twice because of the depth of 2 which is defined by `private Entity0 reference = new Entity0(new Entity0(null));` (`Entity0` is a class without only one property which is a reference to itself) and then the "recursion terminated label".

An SSCCE can be found at https://gitlab.com/krichter/jsf-avoid-nested-rendered-evaluation.

I'm using Primefaces 6.2 on Payara 4.1.2.181.

Comment: Check http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2016/02/recursive-tree-of-composite-components.html. Need to find the stackoverflow counterpart of it

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks a lot. I proposed to link the blog post in the answer to the question of which this one is a duplicate.